# Optimizing a large Django project by moving certain process to dedicated machine (microservice?)

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, microservices

I'm working on a large Django project that uses application server(s) to process Latex. As our site grows, the Latex processing is affecting performance when site traffic is high.

One idea I had was to move the Latex processing to a separate EC2 instance optimized for: processing Latex using TexLiv, creating a PNG, saving PNG to S3, and then returning a URL for the image. I also need to communicate with my existing Django ORM to update the object's image URL with the one just created on the dedicated machine.

I have several questions:
1) what kind of EC2 instance should I use (computer or memory optimized?)
2) what kind of web server should I use on this dedicated Latex processing machine (is this a microservice?) Django, Tornado, Flask?
3) How do I get my existing project to communicate with new, dedicated Latex processing machine.
4) anything else I might be missing

Thanks

Comment: Can you describe your full stack please ? One EC2 with a django app and a bunch of celery workers for the latex processing ? How much worker do you have for the latex processing to "affect performance" ?

Comment: @lee-pai-long: multiple EC2 app-servers with load balancer. Nginx, Redis, Celery. We do not use any Celery workers for latex processing. Perhaps this is something to do? "How much worker do you have for latex processing" -- I don't fully understand...the answer might be zero because there are is no Celery process happening on Latex processing. Thank you.

Comment: Since you're on AWS maybe SQS is the way to go, I would not put a Web Api over celey I'm not sure it will scale very good since you'll have the overhead of the web api. And since celery doesn't support redis cluster I think redis is no longer a solution. Also using SQS seems to have its own list of caveats(https://medium.com/@Twistacz/whats-wrong-with-sqs-and-why-we-gave-it-up-22780d4f48ef). So I guess rabbitMQ is the way to go. But I'm just giving you an educated guess here I've never deploy this kind of infrastructure(being a cluster of async task to support multiple instance of a web app)

Comment: Have redis serve as the message queue and have celery workers on separate EC2 instances listen to the queue. So when the latex jobs need to be run, it will send the job into the redis queue -- workers will then go and process it. (This is a pretty common django setup, can confirm it works really well for the majority of intensive tasks).